# Check if an array contains (only) numeric values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays such as

```
var arrayVal_Int = ["21", "53", "92", "79"];   
var arrayVal_Alpha = ["John", "Christine", "Lucy"];  
var arrayVal_AlphaNumeric = ["CT504", "AP308", "NK675"];
```

- Above `arrayVal_Int` should be considered as (purely) numeric.
- `arrayVal_Alpha` and `arrayVal_AlphaNumeric` should be considered as strings.

I need to check that in JavaScript.

Comment: Any attempts to solve?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions but before you ask, please search for "test array numeric" here

Comment: An array contains more than a single value (usually). Do you want to know if the array contains *exclusively* numeric values?

Comment: try to loop over the array and apply parseInt function to see it returns ture.

Comment: @Touffy.yes.I need to check whether array is purely numeric

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Shortest solution, evals to `true` if and only if every item is (coercible to) a number:

```
!yourArray.some(isNaN)
```

Comment: @A.T. For browser support check out http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.some (basically, works everywhere now)

Comment: Just learned this, except for empty string `""` that will render as false on `isNaN`

Comment: @Mouser The empty string will coerce to zero so that is consistent with « coercible to a number ». You can switch isNaN for a more specific predicate if needed (and in many cases it won’t be needed).

Comment: This solution does not work if there is null

Comment: This solution does exactly what it says. Like the empty string, `null` coerces to zero.  If you need `null` to make the code return `false`, you need to replace isNaN with something more specific.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar need but wanted to verify if a list *contained only integers* (i.e., no decimals).  Based on the above answers here's a way to do that, which I posting in case anyone needs a similar check.

Thanks @Touffy, for your suggestion.

```
let x = [123, 234, 345];
let y = [123, 'invalid', 345];
let z = [123, 234.5, 345];

!x.some(i => !Number.isInteger(i))  // true
!y.some(i => !Number.isInteger(i))  // false
!z.some(i => !Number.isInteger(i))  // false
```

Comment: you could simplify that to `x.every(Number.isInteger)` instead of the double negation :)

Comment: BTW, I would have used `every` if there was a native isNumber function. Since isNaN is the opposite of isNumber and I wanted to use it without creating an extra function `isNumber = n => !isNaN(n)`, I exploited the fact that `∀|¬()` is logically equivalent to `∄|()`. But you don't have to do that with `isInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

Using simple JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
var IsNumericString = ["21","53","92","79"].filter(function(i){
    return isNaN(i);
}).length > 0;
```

It will return true;

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsOnlyNumbers(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] !== 'number' || isNaN(arr[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let array2 = [1, 2, '3', 4];
let array3 = [1, 2, NaN, 4];

console.log(containsOnlyNumbers(array1)); // true
console.log(containsOnlyNumbers(array2)); // false
console.log(containsOnlyNumbers(array3)); // false
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let x = [1,3,46,7,7,8];
let y = [1,354,"fg",4];
let z = [1, 3, 4, 5, "3"];

isNaN(x.join("")) // false
isNaN(y.join("")) // true
isNaN(z.join("")) // false
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There are sequences with non-numeric strings that can join into a valid numeric string (e.g. `"1", "e5"`), and vice-versa (`"1.2", ".3"`).